# How to get the exact position of each div created using Overlay Map Types

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [Overlay Map Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?csw=1#OverlayMapTypes) to create a Grid.

I have already managed to make the dimension of each square (of the grid) correspond to ~2km2 of area when the zoom is equal to 15.

But now I need to know in which square (of the grid) a particular marker (latlng) is.
The problem is that the information obtained does not include the bounds value.

```
getTile(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
```

It would be necessary to know the bounds of each square.

For example: each time the user clicked on the square, he got bounds of that square on the map.

Is there an easy way to get this information using javascript?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

As @MrUpsidown suggested, I'll add to my question a "minimal reproducible example", which is actually a copy of what's in the link above.

```
/*
 * This demo illustrates the coordinate system used to display map tiles in the
 * API.
 *
 * Tiles in Google Maps are numbered from the same origin as that for
 * pixels. For Google's implementation of the Mercator projection, the origin
 * tile is always at the northwest corner of the map, with x values increasing
 * from west to east and y values increasing from north to south.
 *
 * Try panning and zooming the map to see how the coordinates change.
 */
class CoordMapType {
  tileSize;
  constructor(tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
  }
  getTile(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    const div = ownerDocument.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = String(coord);
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + "px";
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + "px";
    div.style.fontSize = "10";
    div.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    div.style.borderWidth = "1px";
    div.style.borderColor = "#AAAAAA";
    return div;
  }
  releaseTile(tile) {}
}

function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 },
  });
  // Insert this overlay map type as the first overlay map type at
  // position 0. Note that all overlay map types appear on top of
  // their parent base map.
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
    0,
    new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256))
  );
}
```

In the example above, how can I get the exact position of each div created.

In order to obtain the coordinates (latlng) of each of the vertices.

And, in this case, the ideal would be that, each time the user clicks on one of the divs, he gets this corresponding information.

It's possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I already pointed you to the [ask] page on your previous question. Pleas read it and ask questions in an appropriate way.

Comment: Hi @MrUpsidown I edited the question. Please tell me if it is ok. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure you are on the right and/or easiest path. Your use case is unclear. Could you not create a grid with Rectangles or even better, with Polygons? The Geometry library has a `containsLocation` method in the poly namespace: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.containsLocation which is by far the easiest way to know when a Marker is contained within a Polygon.